# How to create dispatch style lambda function using Python?

Tags: python, lambda, dispatch

If I have the given dispatch-style function to represent a pair, how can I implement the same using a one-line `lambda` function?

```
# ADT Level 0 (dispatch-style pair)
def make_pair(x, y):
"""Dispatch-style pair"""
    def dispatch(m):
        if m == 0:
            return x
        elif m == 1:
            return y
    return dispatch
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It will lead to bad readability.

Comment: I have an assignment that requires me to do so.

Comment: @LutzHorn This is common in lambda calculus exercises. It shows that functions (and more specifically anonymous functions that aren't bound) can represent pairs (or in general: data constructs).

Comment: @Medvednic if you have an assignment to do this, should you *be doing it yourself*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
make_pair = lambda x,y: lambda m: x if m == 0 else y if m == 1 else None
```

The outer lambda returns an (inner) lambda waiting for an argument `m` that returns the bound variables in the scope created by the outer.

```
>>>one_two = make_pair(1, 2)
>>>one_two(1)
2
>>> one_two(2)
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use imbricated lambdas to return a lambda expression:

```
>>> make_pair=lambda x,y:lambda m:x if m==0 else y
>>> a=make_pair(2,4)
>>> a(1)
4
>>> a(0)
2
```

`lambda m:x if m==0 else y` is (more or less) equivalent to your dispatch function (`a(2)` will return 4 in my case)